# Windows Phone 8.1 TimePicker: how to show only quarters

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a time registration app. The hours can only be submitted with hours and quarters of an hour.

Therefor I would like to use a TimePicker and filter out all minutes-options, except '0', '15', '30' and '45'

Is there any way to do such thing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the official documentation :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.minuteincrement.aspx

```
<TimePicker x:Name="registrationTimePicker" Header="Registration Time" MinuteIncrement="15"/>
```

Comment: It would be better if you added a short code example instead of just linking to reference website